# NLTK CFG.fromstring give ValueError

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, nltk, context-free-grammar

Below is the code which gives `ValueError`

```
import nltk as nl

grammar1 = nl.CFG.fromstring("""
S -> ',' NP VP
NP -> "John" | "Mary" | "Bob" | Det N | Det N PP
Det -> "a" | "an" | "the" | "my"
N -> "man" | "dog" | "cat" | "telescope" | "park"
P -> "in" | "on" | "by" | "with"
V -> "saw" | "ate" | "walked"
VP -> V NP | V NP PP
PP -> P NP
, -> ','
""")
```

`ValueError: Unable to parse line 10: , -> ','
Expected a nonterminal, found: , -> ','`

Whereas the code below works perfectly fine

```
import nltk as nl

grammar1 = nl.CFG.fromstring("""
S -> COMMA NP VP
NP -> "John" | "Mary" | "Bob" | Det N | Det N PP
Det -> "a" | "an" | "the" | "my"
N -> "man" | "dog" | "cat" | "telescope" | "park"
P -> "in" | "on" | "by" | "with"
V -> "saw" | "ate" | "walked"
VP -> V NP | V NP PP
PP -> P NP
COMMA -> ','
""")
```

Why is it so? I want to generate grammar for bunch of data in which punctuation marks are common, also the number of production rules for my grammar have these punctuation in multiple places. Do I have to change the terminal names allover production rules?
I am using python 3.4 and nltk 3.2.1

Comment: Looks like the nltk's CFG module requires the left side of productions to be "identifiers", which follow the same rules as variable names. There won't be a problem with rules like `OF -> "of"`, for example, but you do have to use the names of punctuation marks.

Comment: Could you provide me some references which talk about the rules and conventions that should be followed for writing such production rules.

Comment: I can't sorry. That's why I just wrote a comment and not an answer. Read the nltk book, and study the source. But identifiers, in most programming languages, must begin with a letter and must consist of letters, digits, and underscores (`_`).